# how to remove a specific string from a label

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to remove a specific string out of a label. The label is suppose to print an error message while the input is invalid, as soon as the user changes the textbox input to a number, the error message should disappear for that specific input.

Here is what I tried so far but the "-=" did not work as I expected.

```
Sub errorOutput(toggleError As Boolean, courseNumber As Integer)

    Dim err(6) As String
    err(courseNumber) = "please ensure that what you input in Course " + courseNumber.ToString + " is a number between 0 and 100"

    If toggleError = True Then
        lblError.Text += err(courseNumber)
    Else
        lblError.Text -= err(courseNumber)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you reset the label back to empty before checking all of the errors, and just not add the messages that don’t apply?

Comment: Yes I can, I didn't think of it that way. Thank you

Comment: Further to @Ry-'s suggestion, I would recommend that you have a `List(Of String)` at the class level and you can add and remove error messages as you please. When you want to change what's displayed, simply do this: `lblError.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, myList)`. The error messages will then be display in the `Label`, one to a line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When applied to two `String`s, the `+` operator does *concatenation*. It appends the string on the right-hand side of the operator to the string on the left-hand side of the operator.

(Technically, it creates a *new* `String` object that represents the concatenation of the left-hand and right-hand strings, since strings are immutable in .NET, but that's a technical detail you probably don't care about.)

The `+=` operator is referred to as a *compound assignment operator*. It merges together an operator that modifies the value (in this case, the `+`) with the assignment operator (`=`), so that you can get both at once.

Okay, so you know how this works already. You're using `+=`, and you can append two strings, and everything is good.

So, by way of analogy, you try `-=`. Wait…what should happen? What does it mean to *subtract* two strings? Subtracting two numbers, well, that makes perfect sense. But how do you subtract a string?

It's not obvious what operation would be performed, so the subtraction operator doesn't do anything for `String` objects. It hasn't been defined, because its semantics are not clear. Only concatenation is defined, using the `+` operator (and also the `&` operator).

If you need to "remove" a portion of a string, you will have to write a bit more code, using one or more of [the methods provided by the `String` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string?view=netframework-4.7.2#methods) to spell out exactly what operation you want to happen. For example, you could use the [`String.Replace` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Replace_System_String_System_String_) to replace all occurrences of one string with another string (or even an empty string):

```
Dim message As String = "My favorite color is yellow."
message = message.Replace("yellow", "blue")
```

But in this case, you probably just want to *clear* the Label control first, and then only add in the error messages. This is essentially what [Ry- suggested in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54603183/how-to-remove-a-specific-string-from-a-label#comment96002251_54603183); e.g.:

```
Sub errorOutput(toggleError As Boolean, courseNumber As Integer)

    lblError.Text = String.Empty

    Dim err(6) As String
    err(courseNumber) = "please ensure that what you input in Course " + courseNumber.ToString + " is a number between 0 and 100"

    If toggleError = True Then
        lblError.Text += err(courseNumber)
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

There is some built in things that can be used for validating user input. This is just some info I saved on the subject. Easy to use.

Validation
ErrorProvider

```
Private err As New ErrorProvider()
```

Or add to your form from Toolbox -> Components in Design View

```
.SetError(Control, “Error Message”)
```

Control.Validating

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As  System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles  TextBox1.Validating
        If TextBox1.Text = "" Then
            e.Cancel = True
            err.SetError(TextBox1, "This text box cannot be blank.")
        Else
            err.Clear()
        End If
End Sub
```